# Which operations support automatic gradients?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a fairly complex quantisation layer in my network which contains, among other operations, `tf.tile` and `tf.expand_dims` ops. I noticed that my network did not train well. Looking at some debug output, I saw that the fully connected layer before this quantisation layer got zero gradients for its weights (I used `optimizer.compute_gradients` to determine this). Does this mean that what ever is before the quantisation layer does not update in training?

In general: How do I figure out which operations let gradients pass through and which do not? For instance, do the above mentionied `tf.tile` and `tf.expand_dims` let gradients pass through`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an operation without gradients in your model you will get an error:

```
LookupError: No gradient defined for operation [...]
```

So your problem seems to be somewhere else, maybe you have a multiplication by zero somewhere which kills the gradients. There is not enough information in your question to find the real reason of your problem.

Edit:
I didn't directly answer the question which operations support automatic gradients.

It is not listed in the documentation and I think you can only see it by checking the source code or using the operation and see if you get the mentioned error when you try to optimize the model.

For `tf.tile` and `tf.expand_dims` there are gradients defined.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that input. Good to know. I guess that settles the question as it was posed.

Comment: Is this still valid? I have a toy example where I pass my output through tf.sign, the gradients turn into all zeros (which they are not without this op) and even though I run an optimizer to apply gradients, I can't manage to get a warning about zero gradients no matter what logging level I set. Preferably, I would want these warnings to be very clear to me. Maybe the above is directed at undefined gradients as opposed to zero gradients?